# Как передать сообщение через Socket, ориентируясь на пользователя?

Tags: java, сокет

Собственно, я пытаюсь сделать клиент-серверное приложение, где сервер принимает сообщения, и, в зависимости от того, от кого он получил его, соответсвующим образом обработать. но как идентифицировать клиента - не знаю. Была идея сделать это определяя IP адрес клиента - но это не вриант, т.к. клиент может быть запущен одним и тем же пользователем и из офиса, и , скажем, из дома. а ориентация, всё-таки на пользователя а не на машину.

Comment: COOKIE?


Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вести учетные записи с логином и паролем

Comment: клиентская часть не имеет графического интерфейса и, в общем-то, не должна. а серверная может работать с, скажем, 10ю клиентами одновременно, что означает, что по факту, нужно проверять каждое сообщение от кого оно

Comment: Зачем каждое?.. Не надо. Когда сессия связи установлена, сервер должен запросить у клиента авторизацию и при ее успешном прохождении до конца сеанса связи этот канал остается идентифицирован. Напоминаю, что одновременно сервер может обрабатывать много РАЗНЫХ подключений.

Comment: @devian Смотри: у сервера есть инструкции: если сообщение от васи, то его удаляем, если от пети, отправляем куда-нибудь там, если от сережи, то отправляем обратно. например. Петя, Сережа и Вася отправляют сообщения одновременно. Как сервер должен понять что делать с сообщением?

Comment: devian имеет ввиду, что сессия с клиентом создается одиножды, а учетные данные Вам в любом случае придется использовать, пускай даже и неявно (например на основе сгенерированных ID), Вы же как то должны знать что Вася, это Вася, так дайте ему просто логин вшитый в программу и передавайте это значение при установке соединения. А инструкции на пользователя, это уже дело групп, допустим если Вася_id состоит в группе, которым все можно, то ему все можно.

Comment: @michael вот, ближе к теме. как передать значение при установке соединения?

Comment: Это уже вопрос к описанию методов работы с сокетом, без них вам все равно никуда. Вы же как то уже передаете данные, передавайте первым идентификатор, если идентификатора не зарегистрировано разрывайте соединение, вас обманывают. Так же возможно передать определенный набор байт при самой установке соединения, метод **.Connect();** (по крайней мере в C#, на java не увидел).